# How to uninstall Ubuntu 14.04 and install Windows 7 without dual boot?

Tags: boot, windows-7

How can I install Windows 7 and remove Ubuntu 14.04? I do not have dual boot or anything, when I first installed Ubuntu on my "experiment desktop", I formated my entire harddrive.

Any help with this is very much appreciated, the answers I found so far by searching for it, almost everybody mentioned how to do it by dual boot.

Comment: This question is Windows-related, so not suitable for AU.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the instructions provided with your Windows 7 installation disc.  If you have no desire to keep Ubuntu, then it does not matter what was on the drive beforehand.